# How do i get G Suite user's email usage and capacity?

Tags: php, laravel, google-api-php-client

```
google/apiclient: 2.0

$adminService = new Google_Service_Reports(...);
$userUsageReport = $adminService->userUsageReport;
```

I already tried using the Reports but it gives me an inaccurate result, values are not match with the current storage.

- gmail_used_quota_in_mb
- used_quota_in_mb

Comment: Did you try going though the gmail api and grabing  [user.getprofile](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/getProfile?apix_params=%7B%22userId%22%3A%22me%22%7D)

Comment: @DaImTo I tried, it only counts the total emails on the mailbox. not exactly the storage usage.

Comment: The only thing that shows storage is google drive api as far as i recall which may include usage from gmail i cant remember